# Opencv using camera with matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, matplotlib

I am trying to create a program that will show me different types of gradients of a video I am capturing. This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


cap = cv2.VideoCapture()

while(1):
    bleh, img = cap.read()

    laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
    sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

    plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Original'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(2,2,2),plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Laplacian'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(2,2,3),plt.imshow(sobelx,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Sobel X'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(2,2,4),plt.imshow(sobely,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Sobel Y'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

    plt.show()
```

However, I am getting an error stating that Image data can not be converted to float.

This program works when I replace the video capturing with just an image and feed that directly into the laplacian, sobelx, and sobely transformations.

Can I not sure matplot for video?

Comment: Works for me. What is the dtype of img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with your code then I changed :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
```

to :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

and it worked

This is because VideoCapture needs to know what video device to use on your computer, if you are using your webcam then you have to pass 0 as argument to the function